# HoldForm, ReleaseHold for inputfield

Tags: hold, inputfield

I am working on creating a CDF file for a calculation where I do high-precision evaluation of functions such as N[func,40]. I wrote a Module that takes user function and rationalize it, this way I create a function with user input accuracy. (Shown Below). When I don't use an inputfield my module works well but with inputfield I can't prevent it to be evaluated.

[image]

As you can see I need to avoid the evaluation so that I can evaluate the function in desired accuracy (number of digits). Any idea how I can do this?

Thank you

Erdem

```
Panel[DynamicModule[{fun = 2.1 Sin[Pi z/2.1]}, Column[{

Row[{Style["Function ", 12, Blue, Editable -> False], 
  InputField[HoldForm[Dynamic[fun]], FieldSize -> {55, 3}, 
   BaseStyle -> {12}]}, Spacer[1]]
, Button[Style["Calculate", 14, Green, Editable -> False], 
 Res = upAC[fun]],
Row[{Style["Result ", 12, Red, Editable -> False], 
  InputField[Dynamic[Res], FieldSize -> {52, 2}, 
   BaseStyle -> {12}]}, Spacer[5]]
}],
Initialization :> (upAC[in_] := 
  Module[{out}, 
   out = If[Accuracy[in] == \[Infinity], in, 
     ReleaseHold[Rationalize[in, 10^-Accuracy[in]]]];
   Return[out]];)
]]
```

Asked in
http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/978300

Comment: Please edit both this post and the one you made on Wolfram Community and cross-reference them.

Comment: [`InputField`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputField.html) takes a form as its second argument. One possible form is `Hold[Expression]` which simply holds the expression you input. Will this work for you?

Comment: When I do  `InputField[Dynamic[Hold[fun]]` I can't access to the input field.

Comment: Thanks!  This is so that people who would answer on one site will be aware of any existing discussion on the other site.

Comment: If you add `HoldForm` to `fun` definition inside `DynamicModule` and remove `HoldForm` from `InputField`, do you get what you want?

Comment: No it is not working.

Comment: This is strange, maybe I don't understand what you want, but after you do this `fun = HoldForm`, you get exactly the answer you show in your output 219 in the OP and you can edit the input field as you want.

Comment: You do get it but only when you run the Panel not from the GUI. After that input, for example `Cos[1.5 Pi z]` and calculate. You will see that you will get `Cos[4.71238898038469 z]`

Answer (score 2):

Please tell me if this is what you want, and if not in which way it fails:

```
Panel[DynamicModule[{fun = Hold[2.1 Sin[Pi z/2.1]], Res = upAC[fun]}, 
  Column[{Row[{Style["Function ", 12, Blue, Editable -> False], 
      InputField[Dynamic[fun], Hold[Expression], FieldSize -> {55, 3}, 
       BaseStyle -> {12}]}, Spacer[1]], 
    Button[Style["Calculate", 14, Green, Editable -> False], Res = upAC[fun]], 
    Row[{Style["Result ", 12, Red, Editable -> False], 
      InputField[Dynamic[Res], FieldSize -> {52, 2}, BaseStyle -> {12}]}, 
     Spacer[5]]}], 
  Initialization :> (upAC[Hold[in_]] := 
      Module[{out}, 
       out = If[Accuracy[Unevaluated[in]] == ∞, in, 
         Rationalize[Defer[in], 10^-Accuracy[in]]];
       Return[out]];)]]
```

Comment: Yes it does work. Thank you.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Great! One question. Shouldn't we have `HoldForm` around the RHS in the initialization of `fun` to make sure the very first evaluation of the `Panel` produces the correct expression in the input form?

Comment: @Stitch Good point.  I believe it needs to be `Hold` rather than `HoldForm` to work as desired.  I included this in my answer now.

Comment: Thank you for the update. It is a little detail but important.